# Could not start quickbooks

Tags: sdk, quickbooks

We are currently running the quickbooks sdk and we have created a custom application that is designed to update the server. We use the task scheduler to kick this program off overnight, and it works on most occasions.

Every once in a while, we will get an error in the log that reads:
VendorSync.Program: while submitting requests to QuickBooks: Could not start QuickBooks.

This causes the program to fail and any subsequent attempts as well. We are forced to manually restart the server and rerun the custom app in order to once again get it to start. After doing a lot of research, we have been unable to figure out what could be causing this intermittent problem.

Has anyone else run into an issue with quickbooks? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Best solution seems to be, log off profile, or reboot server, restart SDK app.... But you've already figured that out :-) Welcome to the club.

Comment: Only thing I can think to suggest is to look to see if there is an automated backup (either the internal QB backup or an external backup) is locking the QBW file during the times when you have the problem.